# egit merge tool disabled

Tags: eclipse-plugin, github, egit

I have recently installed eclipse indigo and egit V1.3 and configured my project in it. I am unable to use the Team->Merge Tool as per the documentation in http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Using_Merge_Tool in case of conflicts. The Merge Tool option is disabled. A search in google points me to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339092, but looks like this bug has been resolved in the new version. Is there something else I need to configure ?

I am directly working on the master branch. Am I missing something ?

Comment: What resulted in the conflict? Merge, rebase or cherry-pick? Also, could you please try the newest version of EGit from the following update site (I'm using it and it's very stable): http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly

Comment: Conflict is because of the cherry-pick. I am now installing the nightly build. Thanks

Comment: I installed the nightly build and did a fresh import of my project into the workspace. Then I changed a file through the github dashboard and saved. Modified the same file through my eclipse workspace. Synchronize view now shows a conflict. But the Team->Merge Tool is still disabled :(

Answer (score 0):

[Synchronize View](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Comparing_with_Branches_.28Synchronize.29) is also called "Comparing with Branches".
It does *comparisons* (not merge per se). It allows you to see differences (and detect potential conflict, should you merge them), it doesn't start the merge.

Should you pull/merge/cherry pick the remote branch to your local branch, then the merge tool should be active.

Answer (score 0):

After you get from Eclipse the ugly CheckoutConflictException, the Eclipse-Merge Tool button is disabled.

Git need alle your files added to the Index for enable Merging.

So, to merge your Changes and commit them you need to add your files first to the index "Add to Index" and "Commit" them without "Push". Then you should see one pending pull and one pending push request in Eclipse. You see that in one up arrow and one down arrow.

If all conflict Files are in the commit, you can "pull" again. Then you will see something like:

\< < < < < < < HEAD Server Version \======= Local Version > > > > > > > branch 'master' of ....git

Then you either change it by the Merge-Tool, which is now enable or just do the merge by hand direct in the file. In the last step, you have to add the modified files again to the index and "Commit and Push" them.

Checking done!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after not good merging trying. The option was disabled, and in the repo's view it was missing.

Making reset solved the problem. See image.

[image: Rest option on Egit]